# Error while upgrading rxjs from 6.5.5 to 7.4 in angular 13

Tags: angular13, rxjs7, rxjs-compat

I upgraded my angular version from 10 to 13 so I tried to upgrade rxjs from 6.5.5 to 7.4, rxjs-compat version from 6.6.2 to 6.6.7 that time I was getting the error. Please give me any solution.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

{
"name": "ng-mash-able",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
"@angular/animations": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/cdk": "^13.3.7",
"@angular/common": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/compiler": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/core": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/forms": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/localize": "^13.3.7",
"@angular/material": "^13.3.7",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.3.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/router": "~13.3.7",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
"@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^11.0.4",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^5.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid": "^5.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid": "^5.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.1.0",
"@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^2.0.7",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
"@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^9.0.0",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.27.0",
"@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.0",
"angular-datatables": "^13.0.1",
"angular-dual-listbox": "^6.0.0",
"angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
"angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
"angular2-notifications": "^9.0.0",
"angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
"angular2-tinymce": "^3.3.0",
"angular2-wizard": "^0.4.0",
"bn-ng-idle": "^2.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
"c3": "^0.7.20",
"d3": "^5.16.0",
"datatables.net": "^1.10.22",
"datatables.net-buttons": "^1.6.3",
"datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.6.3",
"datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.5.2",
"datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.21",
"datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.5",
"datatables.net-select": "^1.3.1",
"dynamsoft-javascript-barcode": "^8.0.0",
"echarts": "^4.8.0",
"famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
"flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"font-awesome-scss": "^1.0.0",
"fullcalendar": "^5.1.0",
"igniteui-angular": "^11.1.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
"morris.js": "^0.5.0",
"ng-click-outside": "^7.0.0",
"ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
"ng-select": "^1.0.2",
"ng2-currency-mask": "^9.0.2",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
"ng2-google-charts": "^6.1.0",
"ng2-knob": "^1.1.0",
"ng2-select2": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
"ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
"ng2-ui-switch": "^1.0.2",
"ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
"ngx-color-picker": "^10.0.1",
"ngx-custom-validators": "^9.1.0",
"ngx-echarts": "^5.1.2",
"ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-ui-switch": "^10.0.2",
"peity": "^3.3.0",
"print-js": "^1.6.0",
"raphael": "^2.3.0",
"rxjs": "^7.5.5",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
"screenfull": "^3.3.2",
"signature_pad": "^4.0.4",
"simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
"sweetalert2": "^11.4.14",
"ti-icons": "^0.1.2",
"tinymce": "^4.8.3",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"tui-image-editor": "^3.11.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.5",
"@angular/cli": "~13.3.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.7",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^18.0.0",
"@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
"@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.3",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.3.19",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.6.4"
}
}

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-toasty/**ivy_ngcc**/src/toasty.service.js 6:0-39

Module not found: Error: Package path ./Subject is not exported from package

Comment: Please post any code/errors as text and not in an image, see [here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) why. Can you please also add the affected line of code to your question?